# Is it possible to extend a site-wide template in Django / refer to templates in higher directories?

Tags: django

I would like to have a header/footer that follows throughout the entire site. Currently, I have a base.html file sitting within an app (project/app1/templates/app/base.html) and would like to apply an html template that I can use across the entire site. Is this possible or are templates only referanceable within the app templates folder? Can I have a template sitting in a higher directory such as project/template/base.html or project/base.html and call that so I don't have to copy and paste the same template into each app templates folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a root "templates" directory for the project.

## settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

## project structure

```
└── MY_PROJECT
└── BASE_DIR
    ├── my_proj
    │   └── settings.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── templates
```

For more information Read: https://learnbatta.com/blog/understanding-django-project-structure-26/

Comment: Thank you this worked. Going forward however, do I have to be specific in my app template html files? for example, if I have the following code in project/app/templates/app:

'{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}'

In order to use a template w/in app/templates/app, I'd have to substitute base.html with app/templates/app/appbase.html?

Comment: @HelloColorClear No, you don't need to do that. `{% extends "base.html" %}` should work.